# multiple FileStream on the same file causes write to be ignored

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, filestream

I have a process which have 2 FileStream objects that operates on the same file.
Both objects opens the file using the same method:

`file = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);`

Then I write some bytes to them both using write methods, only the last called write is committed while the other is ignored. Write is called using the following code:

`fh.file.Write(buffer, 0, count);`

`buf` is equal to `"fd"` in both calls and `count` is equal to `2`

I call `close()` for both objects after that. After the program is terminated, the output file only have one of the two "fd"s that should have been written. Why is that happening? I tried calling `Flush()` on both objects, but it doesn't make a difference.

Note: calls to `Write()` are done by the same thread.
the final execution order is like this:

```
open_obj1()
open_obj2()
write_obj1("fd")
write_obj2("fd")
close_obj1()
close_obj2()
```

It seems like a simple problem, but I can't get where the problem is. Does the both FileStreams reads the file pointer at the same place and then tries to write to the same place because they both seek to the end of file? if so, what's the solution for this if I wanted the exact same execution order?

Comment: Why do you need two filestreams on the same file?

Comment: `Does the both FileStreams reads the file pointer at the same place and then tries to write to the same place because they both seek to the end of file?` Yes

Comment: @Michael it's a kind of a test case I need to pass.

Answer (score 1):

See [`Stream.Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position(v=vs.110).aspx); because this property is not shared between your two streams, subsequent writes start at the beginning, thus writing over the previous writes, not unlike switching your text input to overwrite, moving the caret, and typing in new text. Similarly, if you were to write a longer string followed by a shorter one, you would observe the leftover text of the longer string.